# Reduce Redis Memory Usage

Tags: redis

I am moving an existing scheduling data set to redis. This data has schedules, and users. This is a many-to-many relationship.

I store the full list of schedules in a scored zset where the score is the timestamp of the schedule date. I store it like this so I can easily find all schedules that have elapsed and act on those schedules.

I also need the ability to find all schedules that belongs to a user, so each user has their own zset containing duplicate information.

So the data may look like this:

```
s_1000: [ (100, "{..}"), (101, "{..}") ]   # the schedules key
us_abc: [ (100, "{..}"), ]                 # a users schedules key
us_efg: [ (100, "{..}"), ]                 # another users schedules key
```

An actual record looks like this:

```
"{\"di\":10000,\"ci\":10000,\"si\":10000,\"p\":\"M14IB5A2830TE4KSSEGY0ZDX37V93FYX\",\"sse\":false}"
```

I've shortened the keys, and could even remove them altogether along with the json formatting for a really minimal payload, but all the data needs to be there.

This string alone is only 85 chars. Because there is a copy of each record, that would have a total of 170 chars for this record. The key for this would be `us_M14IB5A2830TE4KSSEGY0ZDX37V93FYX_YYMMDD` for another 42 chars. In total, i'm seeing only 255 bytes necessary to store this data.

I've inserted 100k records just like this one in the way I've described. By my count, that should only require 25mb, but I'm seeing this is taking up well over 200mb to store.

The `memory info` for that payload is 344 bytes (x100k = 33mb)
The `memory info` for the schedules key is 18,108,652 bytes (18mb)

The schedules mem usage looks correct.

Here are the `memory stat`s:

```
memory stats
 1) "peak.allocated"
 2) (integer) 3343080744
 3) "total.allocated"
 4) (integer) 201656296
 5) "startup.allocated"
 6) (integer) 3668896
 7) "replication.backlog"
 8) (integer) 0
 9) "clients.slaves"
10) (integer) 0
11) "clients.normal"
12) (integer) 1189794
13) "aof.buffer"
14) (integer) 0
15) "lua.caches"
16) (integer) 0
17) "db.0"
18) 1) "overhead.hashtable.main"
    2) (integer) 5850304
    3) "overhead.hashtable.expires"
    4) (integer) 4249632
19) "overhead.total"
20) (integer) 14958626
21) "keys.count"
22) (integer) 100036
23) "keys.bytes-per-key"
24) (integer) 1979
25) "dataset.bytes"
26) (integer) 186697670
27) "dataset.percentage"
28) "94.297752380371094"
29) "peak.percentage"
30) "6.0320491790771484"
31) "allocator.allocated"
32) (integer) 202111512
33) "allocator.active"
34) (integer) 204464128
35) "allocator.resident"
36) (integer) 289804288
37) "allocator-fragmentation.ratio"
38) "1.011640191078186"
39) "allocator-fragmentation.bytes"
40) (integer) 2352616
41) "allocator-rss.ratio"
42) "1.4173845052719116"
43) "allocator-rss.bytes"
44) (integer) 85340160
45) "rss-overhead.ratio"
46) "0.98278516530990601"
47) "rss-overhead.bytes"
48) (integer) -4988928
49) "fragmentation"
50) "1.4126673936843872"
51) "fragmentation.bytes"
52) (integer) 83200072
```

It looks like the bytes per key is a whopping 1977 bytes.

Why does each key use 344 bytes? Is it possible to tell redis to only use 1byte per char?
Why does redis use so many bytes per key?

Is there a way I can structure my data better so I don't blow out redis on such low amounts of data (I need 100mms of records).

Comment: just a wild guess: have you try using hash instead of string to store a record?

Comment: I haven't. The problem there is a need to store a list of hash in the same key.